# Reference request: Another tangent half-angle formula

Tags: reference-request, trigonometry

Wikipedia's ["Tangent half-angle formula" article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) lists these:
\begin{align}
\tan\frac\theta2 & = \frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta} = \frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta} = \frac{\tan\theta}{1 + \sec\theta} = \frac{1-\sec\theta}{\tan\theta} \\[10pt]
\tan\left(\frac{\eta+\theta}{2}\right) & = \frac{\sin\eta+\sin\theta}{\cos\eta+\cos\theta} \\[10pt]
\tan\left(\frac\pi4 \pm \frac\theta2\right) & = \sec\theta\pm\tan\theta \\[10pt]
\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin\theta}{1+\sin\theta}} & = \frac{1-\tan\frac\theta2}{1+\tan\frac\theta2} 
\end{align}

I found it convenient in doing a geometry problem to use this item, which I derived from scratch (it's routine):
$$
e^{i\theta} = \frac{1+i\tan\frac\theta2}{1-i\tan\frac\theta2}.\tag{1}
$$

So my questions are:

- Is $(1)$ in "the literature"?  (I'm guessing it's in Euler somewhere.)
- Is this in recent textbooks or the like (say published after 1850)?
- Are there known to be certain contexts in which its use is convenient?

(If there's a book or a paper that it's in, I might just add it to the Wikipedia article and cite that.)